# Query string in Html or javascript

Tags: html, query-string

i hava index.html page.in this page i give a href url to TM.htm page.And also i want to send parameter to TM.htm and render it in this page from index.html

in index.html page when i click link in URL it shows TM.htm?a=7 and it works but in TM.htm page i want to get a parameter with this code

```
window.location.search.substring(x..)
```

but instead of it give TM.htm?a=7 it gives index.html .
what should i do

this is index.html

```
<li><a href='TM.htm?a="+marker.ID </a></li>");
<li><a href='TM.htm?a="+marker.ID </a></li>");
<li><a href='TM.htm?a="+marker.ID </a></li>");
```

and in TM.htm in page load i want to get url
with this code window.location.search but it not give TM.html url it gives index.html url
how can i get TM.htm url in TM.htm?

***edited area is below***

this is my index.html page : [index.html](http://e.yazilimsozluk.com/index.html) in here there is a href TM.htm?a=ID...

in index.html when i click link(such as "Patatesli Kek Tarifi" link) 
it goes to TM.htm and in TM.htm page i want to get query string in URL
so in TM.htm page `on load` event i write

```
  $(window).load () 
    {
```

alert(window.location);....

but although i write this in TM.htm  this give me index.html page URL but i want to TM.htm page URL

Comment: Based on the fact that it does not give you the name of the file you expected, I think you placed this piece of code in the wrong file.

Comment: @TimvanElsloo - no his problem is he is caling window.location.[etc] which is getting the QS for the current page not the href

Comment: @PaulSullivan I'm not really sure I understand this. He clicks on the href, which then "redirects" him to TM.htm, and then wants to now the `a`-param, right?

Comment: actually @TimvanElsloo I think you are right - his question is a bit unclear. OP can you make this a bit clearer please

Comment: @TimvanElsloo thank you very much...i edited question ...you can see edited code in edited area..and i preapered demo with link... in index.html there is a href TM.htm page and in TM.htm page i want to URL .i am using window.location in TM.htm page  but it gives index.html url not TM.htm page url

Comment: Hi @TimvanElsloo, if question is still not clear i can give more detail..please help..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are encountering this error due to non codepage 1252 characters in your document i.e. Turkish / odd character encoding.

Create two blank new documents in notepad or textpad (index.html and tm.htm) and make sure it uses ONLY 1252 or standard character encoding. add a single link from index.html to tm.htm and include your script. If it fires as you expect then your problem is the character encoding of your text file.

I believe the odd characters are causing some hidden bug in the browsers them selves.

I tried moving your script, making it a `<body onload="funct()">...</body>`, updating jquery and firebug always showed the old pages scripts after a click from the index page to the tm.htm page. Could only get the script to fire by clicking refresh on tm.htm.

Regards,

Comment: thank you very much...i edited question ...you can see edited code in edited area..and i preapered demo with link... in index.html there is a href TM.htm page and in TM.htm page i want to URL .i am using window.location in TM.htm page  but it gives index.html url not TM.htm page url

Comment: Hi @PaulSullivan, if question is still not clear i can give more detail..please help..thanks

Comment: @user1688401 - See updated answer. basically I think you have odd non standard characters in your code (right at the beggining of the document). Follow instructions to see if it isolates your problem

Comment: thank you.i remove  turkish character and it works but i need turkish characaters such as ı ,ş etc...  what should i do?

Comment: As I don't use Turkish I will have to hunt - I expect you may have to declare your language in the doc i.e. see http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/new-language-decl/qa-html-language-declarations

Comment: adding this meta information to your page may be enough - basically I can see programmers of browsers interrogating this meta information to switch subroutines in the codebase

Comment: @user1688401 could you mark this as up (I know you ahve marked as correct answer but if you mark it up it also says it has some 'skill')

Comment: what is as up? as you can see in this image i marked as answear and i click useful....  http://n1305.hizliresim.com/19/9/mwz4f.png

Comment: dont worry @user1688401 :)